# how can i reset service usb to serial driver that listed in lsmod without reboot system?

Tags: linux-device-driver, usbserial

I have one usb_to_serial that connected my usb
and installed by this command

> modprobe usbserial vendor=0x67b product=0x2303

and connect to other devices via console

and when use of the screen for connecting to console for example

> screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600

i can stop the session by the this command

> fuser -k /dev/ttyUSB0

but when connect to other device console my console empty show

my question is when i reboot the system and connecting the first device via Console any thing is ok but when i need to connect to other device then must be reboot the os thus can to connect new device! there is any method that don`t required to reboot and only reset the usbserial service without reboot?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now me found a method to restart service usbconsole
if you have same problem then can to try kill process by

> pkill -f /dev/ttyUSB0 ; screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600

by this command you kill prior session on Serial Console and create new session for them

Comment: Simple use `picocom`. `screen` has some disadvantages to be used for serial interfaces.

Comment: by using of picocom my console characters is irregular and can not working by console but screen function is to better when i use to console to multiple end point. and so thanks for Helping to learn new function for console

Comment: `fuser -k` sends the SIGKILL signal by default. `pkill` sends the SIGTERM signal by default. You could use `fuser -k -TERM` to make `fuser -k` send the SIGTERM signal instead of the SIGKILL signal. Then you could replace `pkill -f /dev/ttyUSB0` with `fuser -k -TERM /dev/ttyUSB0`.